# Teamcity to fail build with sane message

Tags: teamcity

How could I fail build with sane message/status while running Command line build step?

Or course I can exit 1 in my script but I'll get ugly 'Exit code 1' as a build result.

Comment: In powershell we either throw an error or do a Write-Error

Answer (score 1):

```
function fail_build {
    echo "##teamcity[buildProblem description='$1']" 1>&2
    exit 0
}
```

could be used in script like

```
cd ./logs
if grep -Pqr 'error text regex' *; 
then fail_build "There are errors in logs"; fi
```

More on TC [documentation page](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ReportingBuildProblems).